# org-mode deck.js or reveal.js: inline figure and 2 column

Tags: org-mode

How do I create a deck.js or reveal.js presentation in org-mode that has the following formatting:

- a figure inlined into running text, that is, not on a separate line,
- two columns of material, usually with one column of text and the other being a figure.

I've done considerable searching w/o finding any answers.  These are possible with beamer, but IMO it doesn't look as good.   Thanks.

Also is there any reason to prefer between deck and reveal?   I'm writing scientific presentations.

My system:

uname -a
Linux w540 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

emacs-version is a variable defined in `C source code'.
Its value is "24.5.1"

org-version is a variable defined in `org.el'.
Its value is "8.3.5"

ox-reveal          20160719.28

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use for a Two Column slide with image on the right (you can change the width of each column) :

```
#+REVEAL_HTML: <div class="column" style="float:left; width:70%">
Blablablablabla
 * blablabl
 * more blabla
 #+REVEAL_HTML: </div>

 #+REVEAL_HTML: <div class="column" style="float:right; width:30%">
 #+ATTR_ORG: :width 150
 [[./images/image.jpg]]
 #+ATTR_ORG: :width 150
 [[./images/image.png]]
 #+REVEAL_HTML: </div>
```